# Duals of filters, an explicit formula for meet?

Tags: set-theory, filters

Fix some set $U$. Recall that filters on $U$ are nonempty sets $F$ such that $A\cap B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\land B\in F$.

Replacing every element of $F$ with its complement and simultaneously replacing every $\mathscr{P}U$ with its dual, I get definition of objects which I call *free stars*. (It is easy to show that free stars bijectively correspond to filters by this double "replacement".)

Free stars on $U$ are sets whole complement is not empty such that $A\cup B\in F \Leftrightarrow A\in F\lor B\in F$.

I denote the lattice of free stars ordered by set-theoretic inclusion as $\mathfrak{S}$.

It is easy to prove that union of any (possibly infinite) number of free stars is also a free star. Thus follows that $\bigcup^{\mathfrak{S}} S = \bigcup S$ for every set $S$ of free stars (where I denote $\bigcup^{\mathfrak{S}}$ the supremum on the set of free stars).

My question: Help to find an explicit formula for infimum of any number free stars (both finite of infinite number of free stars).

The following formulas for filters ordered *reverse* to set theoretic inclusion (I denote them $\mathfrak{F}$) proved in [my draft book](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) may help:

$F_0 \cap^{\mathfrak{F}} \dots \cap^{\mathfrak{F}} F_n = \{ K_0\cap\dots\cap K_n \mid K_i\in F_i \text{ for } i=0,\dots,n \}$.

$\bigcap^{\mathfrak{F}} S = \{ K_0\cap\dots\cap K_n \mid K_i\in\bigcup S \text{ where } i=0,\dots,n \text{ for } n\in\mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: The dual of a filter is called an *ideal*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You've misunderstood. Ideal is a filter in dual order. But I take **both** dual order (that is replacing every element of the filter with its dual) and complement of the filter (considered as a set)

Comment: After some thinking, I conclude that it seems that there is no explicit formula in this case

Answer (score 0):

By infimum I assume you mean with respect to the partial order " A<*B  iff A is a subset of B" , for ideals A,B on a set U. In which case, a  non-empty set S, of ideals on U,has a unique <*-infimum, equal to the common intersection of S,iff the common intersection of each finite non-empty subset of S is an ideal.